# EDirectory: Symfony: The parameter "alias_faq_url_divisor" must be defined

Tags: php, symfony, arcasolutions-edirectory

When I start the (customized) [EDirectory](https://www.edirectory.com) app, it is giving me this error when I visit `http://localhost:8000/config.php`. What do I set this parameter to and where do I set it?

```
InvalidArgumentException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 9176:
The parameter "alias_faq_url_divisor" must be defined.
in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 9176
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getParameter('alias_faq_url_divisor') in classes.php line 2330
at Router->Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\{closure}(array('%alias_faq_url_divisor%', 'alias_faq_url_divisor'))
at preg_replace_callback('/%%|%([^%\s]++)%/', object(Closure), '/%alias_faq_url_divisor%') in classes.php line 2340
at Router->resolve('/%alias_faq_url_divisor%') in classes.php line 2299
at Router->resolveParameters(object(RouteCollection)) in classes.php line 2276
at Router->getRouteCollection() in classes.php line 2056
at Router->getMatcherDumperInstance() in classes.php line 2006
at Router->Symfony\Component\Routing\{closure}(object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache)) in ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory.php line 46
at ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory->cache('/cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/wiseher/edirectory/app/cache/dev/127.0.0.1/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php', object(Closure)) in classes.php line 2016
at Router->getMatcher() in classes.php line 1980
at Router->matchRequest(object(MultiDomainRequest)) in classes.php line 2772
at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher)) in WrappedListener.php line 61
at WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) in classes.php line 2544
at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in classes.php line 2459
at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 140
at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in HttpKernel.php line 125
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(MultiDomainRequest), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 64
at HttpKernel->handle(object(MultiDomainRequest), '1', true) in ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php line 69
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(MultiDomainRequest), '1', true) in Kernel.php line 185
at Kernel->handle(object(MultiDomainRequest)) in app_dev.php line 32
at require('/cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/wiseher/edirectory/web/app_dev.php') in router_dev.php line 40
```

I also get this error (2/2):

```
Exception in Settings.php line 79:
Cannot find host localhost for this eDirectory installation
in Settings.php line 79
at Settings->setActiveHost('localhost') in Settings.php line 38
```

I set up the app with `composer update`:

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup.html#installing-an-existing-symfony-application

Symfony 2.8, PHP 5.6.27

Comment: Have a look in `app/config/parameters.yml`. Anything in there?

Comment: Yes, but `alias_faq_url_divisor` is not in there, and there is no obvious value to set it to. I added `alias_faq_url_divisor: x
    alias_contactus_url_divisor: x
    alias_terms_url_divisor: x
    alias_privacy_url_divisor: x
    alias_sitemap_url_divisor: x` but there is a never ending error message with a different value each time I reload the page. The top of the file states `# This file is auto-generated during the composer install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by copying the contents of `app/config/domains/domain.route.yml.sample` to `localhost.route.yml`. I also added the following 2 lines which were in `<domain>.route.yml`:

```
alias_forum_module: forum
alias_forum_allcategories_url_divisor: forum
```

Comment: Nice! I'm not so familiar with `EDirectory`, but that's not where I'd normally expect to find what is the equivalent to the `app/config/parameters.dist` file. Thanks for coming back & answering your own Q. :)